# Why does my c++ compiler put trash characters when displaying build messages?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
||=== Build: Debug in prac4e2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
    C:\Users\...\producto.cpp||In function â€˜void CargarProducto(Producto&)â€™:|
    C:\Users\...\producto.cpp|8|warning: format â€˜%dâ€™ expects argument of type â€˜int*â€™, but argument 2 has type â€˜long int*â€™ [-Wformat=]|
    C:\Users\...\producto.cpp||In function â€˜void MostrarProducto(Producto)â€™:|
    C:\Users\...\producto.cpp|28|warning: format â€˜%dâ€™ expects argument of type â€˜intâ€™, but argument 2 has type â€˜long intâ€™ [-Wformat=]|
    ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
    ||=== Run: Debug in prac4e2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
```

For some reason, either the compiler or the program I'm using just want to display these characters instead of regular special characters. It compiles just fine, and I already checked that the compiler was installed correctly twice, but it's just annoying to read and makes it spepcially hard to understand any errors I might have. Maybe I'm missing some kind of language package from windows?

The IDE I'm using is CodeBlocks. Other people on my same uni course don't have this problem, and neither did I before I changed my PC.

Comment: Don't post a picture of a text. Post a text as a text.

Comment: Probably it will help to also show the hexadecimal values of the characters.

Comment: Most likely your compiler is emitting text formatted using ANSI escape codes, but your terminal/IDE doesn't support ANSI escape codes.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a language pack perhaps? Sometimes when you see that it has to do with Unicode or what @Brian61354270 mentioned.

Comment: You seemed to copy the code (formatted and colored) from a web page. Use the command "Paste as a plain text" in your editor.

Comment: @Brian61354270 in such case this looks differently, for example `[0;32m[----------] [m` This looks more like mismatch of character encoding used by compiler and CodeBlocks

Comment: dump the environment variables see what the local and encoding are set to.

Answer (score 0):

> Similar to [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311239](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311239) using vim, it looks like the Code::Blocks build output window is assuming ANSI character set (extended ASCII) when it is in fact UTF-8. I have no idea whether you can set either Code::Blocks encoding to UTF-8 your your tool-chain's diagnostic log to ASCII/ANSI, but one of those would be the solution I think. Certainly you can set the editor encoding: Settings -> Editor -> General settings -> Font -> Default encoding. That may apply to the diagnostic output too.

–
Clifford